# Make countDownTimer executes right away and then every x seconds afterwards

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

I have a countDownTimer that executes a certain section of codes every 10 seconds when a button is clicked. But it only executes the codes 10 seconds after the button is clicked. How do I make it execute right away, and then every other second afterward?

```
CountDownTimer countDown;

public void onButtonClick (View v) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

countDown = new CountDownTimer(10000,10000)
        {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                start();
                //codes
        }.start();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer

CountDownTimer (long millisInFuture, countDownInterval)

'millisInfutre' means milliseconds after start() until onFinish() is called

Set 'millisInfutre' bigger. And I think there's no need to make first call as a part of a CountDownTimer. Just call it directly.

```
someYourTask(?);
new CountDownTimer(Long.MAX_VALUE, 10000) {
    @Override
    public void onTick(long l) {
        someYourTask(?);
    }
    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        Log.d("SOME_TAG", "FINISH");
    }
}.start();


? someYourTask(?) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute code every 10 seconds, I suggest doing something else.

Execute startRepeatingTask(); when the button is clicked.

```
private int interval = 10000; //every 10 seconds
private Handler handler;

Runnable codeExecuter = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
           //run your code
        } finally {
            handler.postDelayed(codeExecuter, interval);
        }
    }
};

void startRepeatingTask() {
    codeExecuter.run();
}

void stopRepeatingTask() {
    handler.removeCallbacks(codeExecuter);
}
```